# why onload=showField() is used?

Tags: html

```
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2" onload="showField();">
```

In the above element why the attribute onload="showField(); is used. Please help me out . thanks in advance.

Comment: `showField();` is a function. look in the code

Comment: Google maps als does this, to display their maps. When the div is ready they load the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simply executes a JavaScript function called `showField` when the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload?redirect=no) event is fired (i.e. when the page "loads"). We cannot tell you what that function does, because it has been created by some programmer. Check the source code to find its definition and find out what it does.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to call the function `showField` when the page loading is completed

Comment: Indead, a **Javascript** function

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but, when the contents of `body`tag is loaded on to the browser window, it will see the value of `onload` attribute and executes it as JS script.
In this case, `onload="showField();"`, the JS method `showField()` is called.